# using NIFs with rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'am a beginer in rebar and try to build an Erlang application that use NIF with rebar but i have some questions to ask you about:

1.In the .c files i include "erl_nif.h"how rebar tell the compilator about the location of this file

2.when our .c file uses extra libraries .dll,.so where (in the rebar project code) rebar tells the compilator about the location of these file

3.is it possible to use CodeBlocks compilator to compile projects with rebar, i try to do this by adding {port_env, [{"CC","/C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGWp/bin/gcc.exe"}]}.in the rebar.config but i had an error telling me that the path of compilator is wrong

4.what tutorial,articles(for a begginer) do you recomand that helps me undresatnd how rebar works

Comment: Can you post your config files, errors or anything else that would help address the question? It's hard to help debug without some more concrete examples of what's going on.

Comment: https://github.com/vmx/hellonif this is the project that i try to run on windows

Comment: You may want to try running `rebar` with the `-vvv` option, as that enables a ton of debug information that might help you figure out the problem.